# How does Xcode's linker decide where to look for frameworks?

Tags: xcode, compiler-construction, frameworks, linker, warnings

Now I know there are certain standard paths in which the linker looks for frameworks, but where does get it's instructions from, to look in other custom paths?

The problem I've got is a warning, something like this:

```
ld: warning: directory '/Path/to/my/Xcode/Project/../../../../../some/other/src/path/no/longer/in/use' following -F not found
```

It seems to me that something somewhere is storing a relative path to a directory I'm no longer using. I'd been messing around cpl weeks ago with a framework which was located there. In the end I decided not to use it. Haven't worked on the project since then and meanwhile "some/other/src/path/no/longer/in/use" has been deleted. In that sense, the warning makes sense to me, but I just can't for the life of me think or find where this path or framework is still referenced!

I've tried cleaning, emptying the cache, full text search and checked the build settings for any paths I might have added and forgotten about. Can't find anything.

Any ideas please or concrete suggestions of where I should be looking?

Answer (score 0):

It comes from the target setting "Framework Search Paths". Whenever you add a framework, Xcode automatically adds its containing directory to this setting.

Comment: That's what I thought, but there's nothing listed there (neither for debug nor for release configuration)